# "Replace" function in Pandas is not working correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, nonetype

I need to replace some values in my dataframe but it seems that the **"replace"** function is not working correctly.

The function has no effect, it doesn't make any change on my dataframe .

Here is my code:

```
    def energy():
        energy=pd.ExcelFile('Energy Indicators.xls').parse('Energy')
        ...
        ##I need to replace this value by a new one     
        energy = energy.replace("United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland",
                                "United Kingdom", inplace=True)
        ...

        return energy
```

When I put the `inplace=True` parameter, it generates this error :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

---

[Here is the .xls File I am working on](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B80lepon1RrYeDRNQVFWYVVENHM/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2):

Buried in the comments section above is the answer that solved this problem for me:
"replace does full replacement searches, unless you turn on the regex switch. Use regex=True, and it should perform partial replacements as well"

Putting it here in case others are having similar issues.